# Retrieve multiple checkboxes stored as an array

Tags: php

I am working on a form that contains multiple checkboxes (each with its own value). The last checkbox is marked "Other" and, when it is checked, a text input should appear to let the user write his/her own value.

```
<input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="I &amp; O" />I &amp; O<br/>
<input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="Daily Weight" />Daily Weight<br/>
<input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="Foley Catheter" />Foley Catheter<br/>
<input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" onClick="showHide(whatever);" value="" />Other<br/>
<input name="pVital[]" type="text" id="whatever" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

I insert all these values into the same field in my database, as an array of strings, using php's `implode` function:

```
if ((isset($_POST['pVital']))){
    array_walk($spVital, 'GetSQLValueString');
    $spVital = implode(',',$_POST['pVital']);   
}

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO admissionorder (VitalSigns) VALUES (%s)",
                      GetSQLValueString($spVital, "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_PPS, $PPS);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $PPS) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is working fine for insertion, but I encounter a problem in retrieving these checkboxes... with the "other" text input if appropriate.

Comment: format your code and show us some warning/debug/error messages, logs or var_dump of db result

Comment: I have fixed your formatting and English for you, since you couldn't be bothered to do simple things like capitalising the word "I". I think we still need more information, though. You mention a "problem": _what_ problem?

Comment: You say insertion is working, but retrieving the checkbox values is the problem. Yet you only gave sample code for insertion. It would be more helpful to see your code that isn't working.

Comment: @Michael Mior & Marek Sebra: for retrieving these checkboxes I use this php code inside the form:<?php 
$pVital_array = array('I &amp; O', 'Daily Weight', 'Foley Catheter', 'Other');
$pVital = unserialize($row['pVital']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pVital_array); $i++){ 
$checked = in_array($pVital_array[$i],$pVital)? " checked" : ""; 
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"pVital[]\" value=\"$pVital_array[$i]\"$checked> $pVital_array[$i] <br>\n"; 
} but what if the user check 'Other' choice and write some text? How can I retrieve this "combination" of inputs from same field into its right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
<?php 
    $pvitals = explode('|', $row_pInfoRecordset['VitalSigns']);
?>
```

then:

```
<input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="I &amp; O" checked="<?php if (in_array('I &amp; O', $pvitals)) echo "checked"; else echo "unchecked"; ?>" />I &amp; O<br/>
  <input <?php if (in_array('Daily Weight', $pvitals)) echo "checked"; else echo "unchecked";  ?> name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="Daily Weight" />Daily Weight<br/>
  <input <?php if (in_array('Foley Catheter', $pvitals)) echo "checked"; else echo "unchecked"; ?> name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="Foley Catheter" />Foley Catheter<br/>
  <input <?php if (in_array('other', $pvitals)) echo "checked"; else echo "unchecked"; ?> name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="other" onClick="showHide(whatever);" value="other" />Other<br/>
    <input name="pVital[]" type="text" id="whatever" <?php if (in_array('other', $pvitals)) { $vis = 'style="visibility: visible;"'; echo $vis; ?> <?php } else { ?> style="visibility:hidden" <?php } ?>  value="<?php if (in_array('other', $pvitals)) echo end($pvitals); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can see a couple of problems.

First, that array_walk on line 2 isn't doing anything as it's running on an empty... array? string? which is then clobbered. You should be walking along the $_POST element and then imploding what results.

Second, if somebody checks that box for "other" you're going to get an extra empty entry in pVital, which is a much more awkward way of figuring out that box has been checked than giving it its own distinct name.

Third, you're collapsing a bunch of discrete values into a single text field and then expecting to be able to unpack the text field -- maybe by exploding it along the commas? -- and get the discrete values back, which is problematic.

If you actually control the database I'd suggest making a table after the pattern

```
admission_vital_signs(
    admission_order_id INT, 
    vital_sign_text VARCHAR, 
    is_free_text BOOL)
```

to hold said discrete values.

If you don't control the database but do control the output mechanism I'd suggest using a delimiter that doesn't appear in nature -- the pipe "|" is usually good for this -- so you can at least split things cleanly, and maybe preface any freetext with FREETEXT:: ("::" is also generally not found in nature) so you can recognize it when it shows up.

If you don't control the database or the output mechanism you need to edit your original post with what the output mechanism is that you have to work with.

EDITED:

Alright, if I understand correctly, you're retrieving this data from the database and trying to work out from it whether you should tick the appropriate boxes on postback, so you do control the output mechanism. The following set of instructions assume you don't control the database; if you do, making a new table is the way to go here but the method's still crib-worthy.

Name the checkbox by other "pVitalOther', value '1', and the textfield 'pVitalOtherText'. No brackets. Here's some psuedocode for going in and coming out.

```
if isset($_POST['pVitalOther'])
    $_POST['pVital'][] = "FREETEXT::{$_POST['pVitalOtherText']}";

$pvitals = implode('|', array_walk('MySQLEscape', $_POST['pVital']));
//and store $pvitals in the database
```

When you're coming back out:

```
$pvitals = explode('|', $row['VitalSigns']);
$pvitals_last = $pvitals[count($pvitals)-1];
if strstr("FREETEXT", $pvitals_last)
    $lastparts = explode('::', $pvitals_last);
    $pvitalOther = true;
    $pvitalOtherText = $lastparts[1];
```

Then when you go to build the checkboxes pipe in a bit of PHP about like

```
<? php if (in_array('Daily Weight', $pVital)) echo "checked"; ?>
```

right into the middle of those fixed-value checkbox tags. Do the same thing for your "other" based on pVitalOther and set the appropriate initial visibility and value of the freetext input field.

Comment: I modify the code with yours like this:if((isset($_POST['pVital']))){
  array_walk($spVital, 'GetSQLValueString');
  $spVital = implode(',',$_POST['pVital']); 
 }
 if ((isset($_POST['pVitalOther']))){
     $_POST['pVital'][] = "FREETEXT::{$_POST['pVitalOtherText']}";
  $pvitals = implode('|', array_walk($_POST['pVital'],'MySQLEscape'));
 }and the insert query to be:$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO admissionorder (VitalSigns) VALUES (%s)",
                      GetSQLValueString($spVital,$pvitals, "text")); then i add:

Comment: $pvitals = explode('|', $row['VitalSigns']);
$pvitals_last = $pvitals[count($pvitals)-1];
if strstr("FREETEXT", $pvitals_last)
    $lastparts = explode('::', $pvitals_last);
    $pvitalOther = true;
    $pvitalOtherText = $lastparts[1];

Comment: and inside the form i do this:<?php if (in_array('Daily Weight', $pVital)) echo "checked"; ?>
      <input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="I &amp; O" />I &amp; O<br/>
      <input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="Daily Weight" />Daily Weight<br/>
      <input name="pVital[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" value="Foley Catheter" />Foley Catheter<br/>
      <input name="pVitalOther[]" type="checkbox" id="pVital[]" onClick="showHide(whatever);" value="1" />Other
        <input name="pVitalOtherText[]" type="text" id="whatever" style="visibility: hidden;">

Comment: i don't get any syntax error in dreamwaver but i got this warning massage:Warning: strstr() [function.strstr]: Empty delimiter in C:\localhost\www\pps\Patint_selection.php on line 99 which is: if (strstr("FREETEXT", $pvitals_last))

Comment: and this also Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\localhost\www\pps\Patint_selection.php on line 153 which is: <?php if (in_array('Daily Weight', $pVital)) echo "checked"; ?>

Comment: Thank You very much Glazius, I wouldn't be able to solve this problem without your hint.